# Question using maven template and docker template

Tags: java, docker, maven, gitlab-ci, to-be-continuous

I have just arrived on a project which is in the transformation phase and I would like to set up two templates that you propose. Maven and docker. I have two approaches :) but I need your advice.
1st approach: I would like to do the build and the releases + publish on the maven artifactory repo and then make a docker image from the maven release and publish on the docker artifactory repo. This allows you to make jars with maven and build an image from these jars. Am I good at my thinking? Then I wonder how to use the git repo with the Maven release part using gitflow?

2nd simpler approach: my deliverable is a docker image so I publish stable or unstable images on the docker repo. So starting from this principle I can do gitflow and ignore the versioning of my poms with maven. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: First I would think about the need of gitflow..Do you really need that? Templates is the question what kind of requirements such template would have? Do you use a corporate pom ?

Answer (score 0):

Indeed with [to be continuous](https://to-be-continuous.gitlab.io/doc/), both the Maven template and the Docker template support the notion of release.

Personally I find using both releases a bit cumbersome: what is your reference ? Maven releases or Docker images ?

I guess some might have good reasons of using both but I would go the 2nd approach (Docker releases only). By the way, this is a simpler DevOps workflow (a commit on `master` triggers a release, optionally a deployment).